# C++ Multithreading error

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wanted to use a simple way of multithreading but I get this error.

error C3867: 'Client::Start': function call missing argument list; use '&Client::Start' to create a pointer to member

```
Client::Client(PCSTR ipAdrr):
    IP_ADRESS(ipAdrr),
    m_Connection(false)
{   

    std::thread t (Client::Start);
    t.detach();

}

Client::~Client()
{

}

void Client::Start()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;    

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) 
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(IP_ADRESS, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    Connect(iResult);
}
```

Comment: You should add a question.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what to do. Of course you'll also need to provide an object for it to use since it's a non-static member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get pointer of member function, you should use `&`. So, `&Client::Start` is correct, not `Client::Start`.

And I assume `Client::Start` is non-static(=instance) member function. If so, you should pass the `this` pointer.

```
std::thread t(&Client::Start, this);
```

Comment: Alright thanks a lot! First time I use it. Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: @MrEpicosity If my question is useful, please choose it >o< (click the check button)